# Linear Independence and linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $p,q,r$ and $s$ be polynomials of degree at most $3$. Which, if any, of the following two conditions is sufficient for the conclusion that the polynomials are linearly dependent?

i.) At $1$ each of the polynomials has the value $0$.
ii.) At $0$ each of the polynomials has the value $1$.

Anyone have the insights?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

1. $p(1) = q(1) = r(1) = s(1) = 0$ means that they have the form

   $$p(x) = (x-1)p'(x), \quad q(x) = (x-1)q'(x), \quad r(x) = (x-1)r'(x), \quad s(x) = (x-1)s'(x),$$

   for some quadratic polynomials $p'$, $q'$, $r'$, and $s'$.
2. $p(0) = q(0) = r(0) = s(0) = 1$ means that they have the form

   $$p(x) = xp'(x)+1, \quad q(x) = xq'(x)+1, \quad r(x) = xr'(x)+1, \quad s(x) = xq'(x)+1,$$

   for some quadratic polynomials $p'$, $q'$, $r'$, and $s'$.

Which of the two seems to give you the info that you want?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

First find two polynomials satisfying (i) which are linearly dependent and two that are linearly independent. Generalize to three.

For (ii), suppose $\alpha p+\beta q+\gamma r=0$ and evaluate at 0.